# How does the NSTextView implement Truncate Tail?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

[image]

This is what I saw in MAC Note, and it feels great. I'm not familiar with NSTextView, and I'd like to know how it works in each line of Truncate Tail.
Constraints and text changes are clear to me, and now I don't understand how each line can be Truncate Tail.

Comment: You can do so by using 2 `textviews`

Comment: Yes, two NSTextFields.

Comment: Two NSTextField can be achieved, and this is my current program. But I still wonder if it's possible for NSTextView to do so.

Comment: Notes uses 3 `NSTextFields`, title, time and content. Take a look at `NSParagrapStyle` and its `lineBreakMode`, maybe `NSTextView` can do it.